# Using AJAX to send an email

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am attempting to make an AJAX contact form with Webscript (http://webscript.io), but I am running into a problem. Without AJAX, the form worked well and the email was delivered. After trying to add AJAX functionality, I stopped receiving emails through the form, yet the AJAX appears to run successfully. Here is a JS Bin with my example code: http://jsbin.com/aqahok/1/edit. I have a feeling the problem doesn't lie in the Webscript (which I believe you cannot view) but in the JS since the form worked without AJAX.

Thank you for taking a look at my problem and feel free to ask me any questions you may have.

Comment: Try moving your destination to an ajax url: parameter, it is turning 500 server error in jsbin

Comment: You can't post a form cross domain with ajax. That will account for issues in jsbin... and possibly the live form. I notice that an absolute  url is used in ajax code which is why suggest it may be the issue

Comment: Webscript supports CORS, so you can (in most browsers) make cross-domain AJAX calls.

Comment: @585connor You should check the "request log" on webscript.io for this script. It should tell you what the 500 error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript is looking for `input[name="message"]`, but it should be looking for `textarea[name="message"]`. I changed that and tried to send an email. It appears to have worked (no error), so hopefully that's it.

Comment: Ah, yes. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The JS Bin you created makes webscript.io return **500 Internal Server Error** (you can see it in Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools). AJAX part just does not check response and show the "Contact Form Submitted!". So problem is on their side.